# Are objects stored in thread safe collection thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Are the objects stored in a thread safe collection (like CopyOnWriteArrayList) thread safe? Let us say that the objects stored are mutable (not thread safe) then the fact that the collection (here CopyOnWriteArrayList) is thread safe provide any guarantee towards the thread safety of the reference stored in it?

Comment: I'm sorry, what are you asking? Are you talking about the reference variables within the array that is backed by the collection, or the actual objects in the collection?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my question. I was referring to the objects in the collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the objects are not thread-safe; if two threads change a mutable object that they retrieved from a CopyOnWriteArrayList then they'll cause a data race.

If a collection is thread-safe then this means that two threads can add/remove objects from the collection without corrupting it (for example, an ArrayList is not thread-safe, so if two threads each try to add an object to the collection then one or both objects may be lost), however the objects in the collection will still need to be synchronized to make them thread-safe.

Comment: Yes, but too much synchronization could cause the program to run much slower (or in some cases, deadlock).

Comment: Yup, which is why Java moved away from the "always synchronize everything" approach with classes like `Vector` or `Stringbuffer` in favor of the "let the programmer decide what to synchronize" approach with classes like `ArrayList` or `StringWriter`

Comment: @gparyani - "too much" synchronization does not cause deadlock.  Deadlock is caused by *incorrect patterns* of synchronization.  It is the pattern not the quantity that makes the difference.

Comment: @StephenC I was just quoting from *Head First Java*. I guess it was a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

There are some guarantees, usually a thread safe storage is analogous to volatile variables in terms of memory effect.

```
volatile Foo var;              final Vector<Foo> vars = new Vector<>()

// thread 1                    // thread 1
foo.bar = bar;  [1]            foo.bar = bar;         [1]
var = foo;                     vars.set(0, foo);

// thread 2                    // thread 2
bar = foo.bar;  [2]            bar = vars.get(0).bar; [2]

//read[2] sees write[1]        // read[2] sees write[1]
```

Basically, writes before insertion should be visible to reads after retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

The only thread-safe guarantee provided is that the objects will be “safely published”. That is, they will become visible at once for all threads (this includes the reference to the object and its internal state).

Example: if thread A writes X, and thread B reads, B is guarantee to see X as A left it. In other words, the read and write operations are consistent with the order in which they happen.

There are other ways to accomplish the same thing like using `final`, or `volatile`, or `AtomicReference`, or a lock (this is what the thread-safe collections are doing), or a static initializer. See the book “Java Concurrency in Practice” for details.